# What to do with this edit?

Tags: discussion

I came from this question [Check if element is list or another object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064747/check-if-element-is-list-or-another-object) It was different as you see in this picture;

[image]

OP asked his question with JSON etc. and editer deleted all of them, isn't change the actual question? What to do with that now? The edit basically change all the question logic and OP can't declined that probably because editer has high rep.

Comment: The editor is justifying his edit in [a comment below the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064747/check-if-element-is-list-or-another-object#comment44509983_28064747). It may seem radical, but there doesn't seem to be any JSON involved. The OP can always roll back the question to an original revision though. High-rep editor or not.

Comment: @Bart Check the original question. OP trying to give examples there I think and edit clearly messed up

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I removed the word "JSON" from the question because there was no JSON involved in the question. We see this in the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag all the time, but it's the same regardless of language.

JSON is a *textual* notation used for data interchange.

So, say you receive something as a *string* (the response to an XHR call, reading a file from disk, a parameter in a form post, etc.). That *string* may contain the characters `{"foo":"bar"}`, which in that string represent an object in JSON (e.g., a "JSON object").

Once you've deserialized (parsed) the text, you have an object in your language's native sense. JSON is no longer involved in any  way.

Comment: Who better to answer it than the editor himself. +1

Comment: Got it, it seems like the edit changes whole question logic.

Comment: @howaboutNO: I don't see how. The question is about how to do something with a Python object, nothing to do with JSON. By removing the irrelevancy, hopefully we improve the chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus: :-) I only found out about this thanks to [Bart](http://stackoverflow.com/users/488657/bart), who threw a comment on the question to let me know.